# Undefined reference to 'glib'

Tags: gtk, codeblocks, glib

I would like to parse a config file using glib in Codeblocks which I use. So I want to do exactly the example which is described [here](http://gtkbook.com/tutorial.php?page=keyfile) first. I have a file named myconfig.cfg and and a code programming.c. I just copy and paste the code to see if glib works but unfortunately it does not work. I did the installation of glib2.0 using sudo apt-get, I found where are the libs in glibs using

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0
```

and in this path

```
project->Build Options->Compiler Settings-> Other Options
```

I added

```
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/arm-linuxgnuebihf/glib-2.0/include
```

When I build and run the programming.c I have these errors

```
-------------- Build: Debug in programming ---------------
gcc -Wall  -g -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include  -std=c99    -c /home/pi/Desktop/programming/main.c -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/programming obj/Debug/main.o    /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16 
obj/Debug/main.o: In function `main':
/home/pi/Desktop/programming/main.c:22: undefined reference to `g_key_file_new'
/home/pi/Desktop/programming/main.c:26: undefined reference to `g_key_file_load_from_file'
/home/pi/Desktop/programming/main.c:28: undefined reference to `g_log'
/home/pi/Desktop/programming/main.c:34: undefined reference to `g_slice_alloc'
/home/pi/Desktop/programming/main.c:37: undefined reference to `g_key_file_get_string'
/home/pi/Desktop/programming/main.c:39: undefined reference to `g_key_file_get_locale_string'

/home/pi/Desktop/programming/main.c:41: undefined reference to `g_key_file_get_boolean_list'
/home/pi/Desktop/programming/main.c:43: undefined reference to `g_key_file_get_integer_list'
/home/pi/Desktop/programming/main.c:45: undefined reference to `g_key_file_get_string_list'
/home/pi/Desktop/programming/main.c:47: undefined reference to `g_key_file_get_integer'
/home/pi/Desktop/programming/main.c:49: undefined reference to `g_key_file_get_double_list'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 6 seconds)
11 errors, 0 warnings
```

Am I missing something? I tried also to do in the same way with libconfig but again I have undefined reference. Is the problem the path?

**UPDATE**

With the usage of pkg-config --libs glib-2.0 it returns me -lglib-2.0

In Codeblocks I inserted it(lglib-2.0) in

```
project->Build Options->Linker Settings-> Link Libraries
```

and now I have this error:

```
**(process:3751): ERROR ** No such file or directory  
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Comment: You missed out `-`, you should add `-lglib-2.0`. Also it might be better to use `\`pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0\`` for compiler settings option and `\`pkg-config --libs glib-2.0\`` for linker settings (Please note the `\`` at the beginning and the end). Code::Blocks also allows to include library by browsing and selecting them in linker settings (btw which version of Code::Blocks are you using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not linking against the library, which is why you're getting linker errors ("undefined reference").

Check the output of `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`, *without* `--cflags`, and make sure it's incorporated in your project settings somehow.

Comment: pkg-config without cflags returns me -lglib-2.0

Comment: @dali1985 Exactly, that's the compiler flag needed to ask it to link in the library. You need to tell Codeblocks to include the same.

Comment: I did it now(maybe wrong) and as you can see in my update I have new error!!